# Consume SOAP Webservice in UWP

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, win-universal-app, webmethod

I'm trying to consume SOAP Web Service information added in "Services References" and in Java or in a type Forms project, it works perfectly.
I tried to do the same in UWP, but the web methods are all asynchronous and I am not realize the call of the same.

The customer was created in WSO2 studio using JDBC.

Can anyone give help on how to consume a SOAP service in the WSDL address was added to the "Service References"?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What is exact problem? Some code fragments would be helpful as well.